# Disabling animation in Ionic toasts

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How can I disable animation in ionic toast?

I was able able to remove all animations by:

```
imports: [
   ...
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      animate: false // disable animation
    })
  ],
```

But how can I do it only for toasts or just a single toast?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with adding a custom css class:

```
let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
  message:"test",
  cssClass:"my-toast",
  position:"top",
  duration:500
})
toast.present()
```

Under app.scss add the class with:

```
.my-toast{
     .toast-wrapper{
        transform: translateY(0%)!important;
     }
 }
```

Depending on the position of the toast you might have to adapt the css.

Comment: @Ari Yes I did actually. Strange. Did you put the class in app.scss? Not in the page scss, it must be global.
Otherwise, remove the duration for a moment, so the toast stays, then you can play around with the element inspector in the browser and see if the css applies.